# Unable to solve flash error 5000: The class ... must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip'

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, cs4

I'm getting the following error on my flash project
5000: The class ... must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.
I looked at the class and made sure that I import flash.display.MovieClip and I do. I tried to change the base class in the linkage to flash.display.MovieClip but I got the following message: "The base class specified is a native class and will be defined in the player at runtime. It cannot be edited."

How can I fix this issue?
Thanks in advance,
Kfir

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306256/5000-the-class-must-subclass-flash-display-movieclip-since-it-is-linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just had the same bug in another project and decided that I should post the solution. For some bizarre reason this error may occur when the references of the project are invalid.
In my case all I had to do is go to File->Publish Settings->Flash->Settings and update all the paths there. That solved my problem.

I hope this will help other people out there and maybe the someone from the flash team will see this and patch this bug.

Comment: What paths were updated? I'm looking at my settings and I don't see where I can update paths. http://screencast.com/t/1kyEQJjWMu

Answer (score 3):

importing the `MovieClip` class gets you halfway there, you have to actually extend the class with `MovieClip` as well.

ie)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip

    public class MyClass extends MovieClip
    {

    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when transfering my files from my desktop computer on my laptop. Actually I tried all I can, but the kfir solution put me on the good way... Refreshing all the paths in File->Publish Settings->Flash->Settings wasn't enough for me... I also had to rewrite all the paths to classes in the miniclip properties. To be more precise, I even had to remove it, click on the tick icon (to validate the path blank), and rewrite the path again and re-tick...

Sounds really wired but does work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I exported the Publish Settings from other flash that worked well, 
imported them in the document that gave me error 5000, and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I work on an animation file project and when I got the same error I tried a lot of ways to fix it without losing the privilege of the camera ... I search in my file for the corrupted movie clip and I discovered that's its a layer I copied/imported from adobe illustrator and has a mask on it that the animate read it as a movie clip but couldn't render it as one so I just removed the mask and the file rendered normally

all the solutions I found online are so complicated, just read the error and find it simple